# Plotting multiple excel sheets on the same graph

Tags: python, excel, pandas, matplotlib, plot

I have [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z60qb.png) excel file that i need to plot. So far my code looks like this

```py
import pandas as pd 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

file = 'weatherdata.xlsx'


def plotMeteoData(file,x_axis,metric,*list_of_cities):
    
    df = pd.ExcelFile(file)
    sheets = df.sheet_names
    print(sheets)
    df_list = []
    for city in list_of_cities:
        df_list.append(df.parse(city))

    x=range(len(df_list[0][x_axis].tolist()))
    width = 0.3
    
    for j,df_item in enumerate(df_list):
        plt.bar(x,df_item[metric],width,label = sheets[j]) #this isn't working
        x = [i+width for i in x]
        
    
   
    plt.xlabel(x_axis)
    plt.ylabel(metric)
    
    plt.xticks(range(len(df_list[0][x_axis].tolist())),labels=df_list[0][x_axis].tolist())

    


    plt.show()
    
t=['Αθήνα','Θεσσαλονίκη','Πάτρα']
plotMeteoData(file,'Μήνας','Υγρασία',*t)
```

and gives [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZQ8lX.png) output.
Each color represents an excel sheet, x-axis represents the months and y-axis represents some values.
I've commented the line where I'm trying to add some labels for each sheet and I'm unable to. Also if you look at the above output the bars aren't centered with each xtick. How can I fix those problems? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically you use plt.subplots, as it gives you more control over the graph. The code below calculates the offset needed for the xtick labels to be centered and shows the legend with the city labels:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

file = 'weatherdata.xlsx'


def plotMeteoData(file,x_axis,metric,*list_of_cities):
    df = pd.ExcelFile(file)
    sheets = df.sheet_names
    print(sheets)
    df_list = []
    for city in list_of_cities:
        df_list.append(df.parse(city))

    x=range(len(df_list[0][x_axis].tolist()))
    width = 0.3

    # Calculate the offset of the center of the xtick labels 
    xTickOffset = width*(len(list_of_cities)-1)/2
    
    # Create a plot
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    
    for j,df_item in enumerate(df_list):
        ax.bar(x,df_item[metric],width,label = sheets[j]) #this isn't working
        x = [i+width for i in x]

    ax.set_xlabel(x_axis)
    ax.set_ylabel(metric)

    # Add a legend (feel free to change the location)
    ax.legend(loc='upper right')

    # Add the xTickOffset to the xtick label positions so they are centered
    ax.set_xticks(list(map(lambda x:x+xTickOffset, range(len(df_list[0][x_axis].tolist())))),labels=df_list[0][x_axis].tolist())
    
    plt.show()
    
t=['Athena', 'Thessaloniki', 'Patras']
plotMeteoData(file,'Month','Humidity',*t)
```

Resulting Graph:
[image: Resulting graph with random data]

The xtick offset should account for different numbers of excel pages. See [this](https://matplotlib.org/3.5.0/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.legend.html) for more information on legends.

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive answer. I wish I could upvote but i don't have the reputation yet.